# What is the source of Perek Shira

Tags: provenance, authorship, perek-shira

What is the source of Perek Shira. That is; when was it composed, and by whom?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perek_Shirah) it is mentioned as early as the tenth century. is there any evidence that it is older than this.

(Note I am not looking for unsubstantiated claims, but rather, rigorous assertions based on evidence such as earliest references, literary analysis, etc.)

Comment: Surmisal - While not specifically Perek Shira as we currently have it, perhaps the concept came from King Solomon? See I Kings 5:13.

Comment: Commentless downvoter?

Comment: I didn't downvote. But, I'm curious as to why I got notified on @mevaqesh's comment if he didn't include my name, and I'm not the OP.

Comment: @DanF when the OP comments on a post with only one other commenter the system assumes he/she is replying to the original comment and notifies that person.

Comment: I had heard that David HaMelech composed it, though I don't have a source.

Comment: @DonielF That is the legend. It was to counter this assumption that I specifically asked for evidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to most scholars Perek Shirah is an anonymous work, the period of its composition and its significance may be deduced from literary parallels.

According to [Encyclopaedia Judaica](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0028659287), vol XV, p. 760:

- Perek Shirah has been preserved in more than 100 manuscripts, 20 of them copied in
  the Middle Ages, including geniza fragments, the earliest dating from
  about the tenth century.
- It is first mentioned in a polemical work of *Salmon b.
  Jeroham, a Jerusalem Karaite of the first half of the tenth century
- The first printed edition, with a commentary by [Moses b. Joseph de
  Trani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ben_Joseph_di_Trani) (printed as an appendix to his Beit Elohim; Venice, 1576), was followed by dozens of corrupt
  editions, generally accompanied by commentaries.

**On the date of composition**:

Notice that the records mention *copied manuscripts* of the tenth century, not date of its composition. According to [Malachi Beit Arié](http://www.huji.ac.il/dataj/controller/ihoker/MOP-STAFF_LINK?sno=198929&Save_t=), Professor at the Hebrew University of Jerusalem, who prepared a critical edition of the text ( פרק שירה: מבואות ומהדורה ביקורתית, עבודת דוקטור ,1966) Perek Shira constitutes one of the earliest compositions
belonging to the early [heikhalot literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hekhalot_literature). Although
strictly speaking a liturgical work and not a midrash, it preserves many tannaitic midrashic ideas and texts and
may have been edited into its current form as early as the end of
the tannaitic period.

Dr. [Shulamit Laderman](http://www.schechter.edu/StaffMember.aspx?ID=19&SM=1a&Dept=SIJS), from Hebrew University of Jerusalem, also agrees when she says:

> The prayer’s midrashic framework and its inclusion of biblical verses
>   confirm its early origins. For example, the Song of the Trees
>   mentioned in 1 Chronicles 16:33 and in Psalm 96:12, which appears in
>   the third chapter of Perek Shirah is also quoted in the apocalyptic
>   vision of God’s Throne, ma’aseh merkavah, described in both the
>   Palestinian and the Babylonian Talmud, which seem to allude to a link
>   between Perek Shirah and early mystical apocalyptic literature. *Laderman, Shulamit*: [Images
>   of Cosmology in Jewish and Byzantine Art: God’s Blueprint of Creation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9004233245),
>   p. 83.

Also supporting an older origin, J. M. Baumgarten argues that its author knew Psalm 151 which was not knows to scholars in hebrew until the discovery of the DSS. See [Perek Shirah, An Early Response to Psalm 151](http://www.jstor.org/stable/24606887?seq=2&loggedin=true#page_scan_tab_contents)” Revue de Qumran 9 (1978).