# Publicizing that you were rescued and how you achieved this - origins

Tags: tefilla, segulah, perek-shira

Where I live - in Jerusalem - it's not uncommon to see signs like this:

[image: I said it 40 times and was saved]

*I said Perek Shira for 40 days and was saved. I promised to publicize this.*

Sometimes it's about other good deeds, usually it's about Perek Shira. (See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/72937/501) for the origins of Perek Shira.)

Essentially, the person says (to himself and Hashem) "I will say Perek Shira for 40 days so that in the merit of doing so *I will get engaged/cured/whatever is bothering  me* and if my prayers are answered I will publicize this".

Where does this concept come from of promising to publically publicize one's redemption - **and how it was done** -  if one is redeemed after doing something?

Any ideas, hints, stories and even sources are welcome.

(I think the concept of publicising a redemption per se can be easily sourced.)

Comment: I feel very angry with this practice, where **only people that succeed publish their positive results** and that creates a huge **availability bias**. Same is gruesomely true with סיפורי צדיקים where we hear only the positively ending stories creating that that צדיק is 100% effective! And **especially with Zedakkah claims** (broadcasted freely on every Religious radio channel in Israel) - just donate a hundred dollars every month for 5 years and you will see miracles!

Comment: Although saying Tehillim or giving Zedakkah or visiting Rabbis are positive Mitzvah on their own, the whole publication turns the system in a sure הונאה if not a scam.

Comment: @AlBerko brings up a good point. We don’t realize that even when our tefillos don’t seem to be effective, they always have some impact. But since these kinds of stories are the only ones publicized, everyone thinks that if you daven for something you automatically get it.

Comment: The last line of the Aruch Hashulchan - Orach Chayim 230:5 says כללו של דבר: לעולם יתפלל אדם על העתיד ויבקש רחמים מלפניו יתברך ויתן הודאה על העבר, ויודה וישבח כפי כחו, וכל המרבה להודות לד' הרי זה משובח, וכמאמר הכתוב: "טוב להודות לד' ולזמר לשמך עליון”. This may be a source for people wanting to share the good that happens to them.

Comment: Don't they sell in the Shuk T-shirts that says "I said Perek Shira for 40 days and all I got was this lousy T-shirt"?

Comment: On the verse in Ps. (109:30) "א֘וֹדֶ֤ה יְהוָ֣ה מְאֹ֣ד בְּפִ֑י וּבְת֖וֹךְ רַבִּ֣ים אֲהַֽלְלֶֽנּוּ", Radak comments "when you rescue me I will thank you and praise you in public so they know that all is from Him and they will then trust Him".

Comment: @Oliver - as I wrote, that part is easy; but where do we get the part of publicizing (and promising to do so) "how it was done"?

Comment: @DannySchoemann I understood that, at least according to Radak's wording, the person is publicizing how he was saved and that's why others will be convinced to "trust in Him". If he merely praises God, e.g. he publicly exclaims "God is all-mighty", how would it lead others to trust in Him?

Answer (score -1):

I also live in Jerusalem, and I was also young once, and in the beginning of my Teshyvah I desperately needed a fast and a sure cure for my Shlom Bays problems (also triggered by Teshuvah). As you mentioned, the Haredi neighborhoods in Jerusalem are full of promising publications: just give some Tzedokeh, daven at the W.Wall etc, so I asked my Rabbi Z"L which one should I do to seek my eternal redemption!

And he said:

> "You sound like a poor needy man that needs a medicine but does not have money to pay the doctor. So he decides to walk to the doctor's house and sit by the window and write down all the prescriptions the doctor gives to his patients!"

**השגחה כללית works that way** - you can hear scientific researches and count on them, but **השגחה פרטית doesn't work that way** - each one has his own private way of conduct with Hashem.

Therefore, it is a generally good Mitzvahs - to say Tehhilim, to give Tzedokkoh etc, but it is erroneous to start thinking that it became a proven cure for everyone. THis approach results in questions like : "**I gave thousands of dollars for Tzedokeh and davened Neitz for 5 years, but this pimple on my hand won't go! What do I do wrong?**"

Comment: While I happen to agree with this mindset, I don't think you're answering the question. The question is 'Are there sources for X' and you're answering 'X is a bad thing' (without giving a source for it). It seems like this would fit better as a supplementary comment to your comments on the question.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Sorry I've read this line *"Any ideas, hints, stories and even sources are welcome"*

Comment: Downvote  - agreeing with @Salmononius2